# Meaning of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sup$ $ a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a real sequence $\{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$. Now if I write $A = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }$ $ \sup$  $ a_n$  , what do I actually mean by this? I mean if $a_1 , a_2, . . . $ is my sequence then $ \sup$ $ a_n$ is a single value. Then what is the point of taking its limit? Am I interpreting $\sup$ $ a_n$ in a wrong way?

Comment: Hm. On first read, I thought of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$, which is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$ (or equivalent definitions). But that notation taken literally seems to make $\sup$ perfectly useless… Side note: I urge you to write $\sup$ (`$\sup$`) instead of $sup$ (`$sup$`). It is an operator after all.

Comment: @Arthur I mean the way he wrote it the index $n$ is governed by the limit, hence $\sup$ cannot influence it, so it seems $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sup\{a_n\})$, which is perfectly equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Of course $\limsup$ is different from $\lim_n\sup$.

Comment: See my answer below for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639298/meaning-of-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sup-a-n#comment3342909_1639298), what I mean is that, if I take the notation literally, it seems to mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{a_n\}$, that is, the limit for $n\to\infty$ of the supremum of the singleton set of $a_n$, which of course is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. So the notation is certainly not precise.

What it probably means is the [limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior). Now I have seen at least two equivalent definitions of this, and the comment I posted mentions a third "easy" equivalent definition, which sort of justifies the notation $\limsup$. So I think I should expose these definitions and prove they are indeed equivalent.

1. The first definition I ever saw of limit superior is the following. Consider the sequence $a_n$. Consider all of its subsequences. Consider all those that have a limit -- which *doesn't* necessarily imply convergence, which is where the now-deleted answer went wrong as a comment posted shortly after it pointed out:

   [image]

   The set of all those limits is called the *limit class* (note: I made the term up by literally translating the Italian [*classe limite*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_limite) -- I am Italian and studied everything in Italian -- and Wikipedia seems to have no English article for that thing). Call it L. We define:

   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup L.$$

   Dually, we define the *limit inferior* as:

   $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf L.$$
2. Over a year later, in Measure theory, the professor tried to justify the measurability of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of measurable functions via $\sup$s and $\inf$s. I went "WTF??" and opened Wikipedia, to find the following two definitions:

   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf_{n\geq0}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k,\qquad\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup_{n\geq0}\inf_{k\geq n}a_k.$$

   Oh really?, I thought. So I tried to prove they were equivalent definitions, and succeeded. Below this numbered list I will prove the equivalence for $\limsup$ in what should be practically the same way as I proved it back then, which means almost 2 years ago.
3. Naturally, the question as to why it was denoted that way, which was open with definition 1 since it sounded like they should actually be $\sup\lim$ and $\inf\lim$, was all the more open with this. But then one realizes that $b_n:=\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$ is a nonincreasing sequence, and hence its limit is also its $\inf$, so definition 2 is trivially equivalent to:

   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{n\geq k}a_k,$$

   which fully justifies the notation. An analogous thing holds for the $\liminf$, with the $\inf$ sequence being nondecreasing and hence having its $\sup$ as its limit.

OK. So what has definition 1 got to do with definition 2? They are equal. Let us call:

$$A:=\sup L,\qquad B:=\inf_{n\geq0}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k.$$

Take any subsequence $a_{n_k}$. Notice how:

$$\sup_{\ell\geq n_k}a_\ell\geq a_{n_k}.$$

Limits preserve "broad" inequalities ("" because I am not sure that is the right adjective, it should be the opposite of *strict* inequalities), so:

$$\lim_k\sup_{\ell\geq n_k}a_\ell\geq\lim_ka_{n_k}.$$

But for any sequence, the limit on the right will be, as noted in item 3, the number $B$. Hence, for any sequence, $\lim a_{n_k}\leq B$. Take the $\sup$ on the left, and we get:

$$A\leq B.$$

And half the work is done. Now take $\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$. By definition of $\sup$, there must exist $k_n\geq n$ such that:

$$a_{k_n}\geq\sup_{k\geq n}a_k-\frac1n.$$

That gives us a subsequence of $a_n$. Now let us take the limit for $n\to\infty$ of that inequality. We get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{k_n}\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k-0=\inf_{n\geq0}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k.$$

Then again, the LHS is the limit of a subsequence, so $A$ is at least as great as that LHS, whereas the RHS is $B$. Hence:

$$A\geq B.$$

Which yields our conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The supremum makes sense for sets, not for individual numbers - so writing $\sup a_n$ with no indexing or other criterion is vague at best. You can write $\sup_n a_n$ to represent the supremum over an entire sequence (again, regarded as the set of values $\{a_n : n \in ...\}$), and many would interpret just $\sup a_n$ in that manner. You can also write

$$\sup_{n \ge k} a_n$$

to represent the supremum of $\{a_n : n \ge k\}$. In that case, something like

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{n \ge k} a_n$$

makes sense, and defines the limit supremum of the sequence.

Comment: So basically I am creating infinitely many convergent subsequences out of this sequence and then taking its supremum?

Comment: @Dark_Knight I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. $\sup_{n \ge k} a_n$ is a *number*, so you can think of this as the limit of the sequence whose terms are these numbers.

Comment: @ T. Bongers - I am not getting the point of taking limit after supremum has been taken?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Because the limit supremum only depends on the eventual behavior of the sequence. If $a_1$ is really large, we don't care; but if infinitely many $a_n$ are large, we do care.

Comment: @ T. Bongers - So can we replace this limit with  - $\sup a_n$ for every $n \in \mathbf{N}$ ?

Comment: No - that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35258/discussion-between-dark-knight-and-t-bongers).

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't have time to carry out an extended discussion.

Comment: @Dark_Knight you are taking the supremum of a set which depends on $n$, precisely $\{a_n,a_{n+1},\dotsc\}$, so you are producing a sequence of such suprema, and hence it makes perfect sense to ask if it has a limit, and what the limit is. Hopefully this clarifies the «point of taking the limit after the supremum has been taken».

Comment: As for «can we replace this limit with - $\sup a_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$?», no, clearly not. Suppose $a_1=10$ and $a_n=\frac1n$ for $n\geq2$. Then $\sup a_n=10$, but $\sup_{k\geq n}a_k=a_n$ for all $n\geq2$, hence the limit superior is 0. In fact, the sequence converges to 0.